# Possibly naive question about quantized space-time

Tags: cosmology, quantum-gravity, quantization

I beg your pardon in advance if this question is *naive*.

In Quantum Mechanics, discrete values of measurements occur <del>only</del> in relation to *bound* states. This is because of the general solution for the time-independent Shroedinger's equation.

Similarly, in order to quantise space-time, do we need to make space-time compact? How would a *compact* space-time look like? Would we simply need close it by including $\infty$? Is that physical (infinity doesn't sound very physical to me)?

Comment: "Naive question". Really bro? I didn't even able to understand yiur question! . Questions are never naive just the perception to see it, decides.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Discrete eigenvalues for measurable observables in QM occur more broadly than just for bound states. For example angular momentum, whether orbital or spin, is always restricted to discrete eigenvalues for all systems, free and unbound as well as bound systems. It is the case, however, that discrete spectra is 'associated' with compact geometries. Thus the angular momentum operators are the generators of rotations and the group of rotations is a compact group.

At this stage of our understanding, one can not make a final statement about possible discrete quantization of space-time since we have no established/corroborated theory that entails such quantization. However, recent research in the Loop Quantum Gravity research program looking for a quantum theory of gravity, has led to the result that if the LQG approach holds, then the boundary surface areas and the internal volumes of compact space-like regions of space-time must have discrete spectra.